# SQLite doesn't treat || like OR

Tags: sqlite, operators, operator-precedence, or-operator

I'm self-answering in the name of posterity. The question was why this SQLite query doesn't do what I expected:

```
SELECT is_current FROM sp_table WHERE is_current != 1 || is_current IS NULL;
```

It only selects rows where is_current is NULL! Bah.

Comment: Could you at least give your question a good title so others can find it?

Comment: Also it is not only in sqlite where `||` doesn't do what you thought it did...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in SQLite the || operator is not a logical or!  It's a string concatenation operator.

OR is the correct operator.

Also, || has higher precedence than all other operators in SQLite so my expressions weren't even being evaluated in the order I thought.

The correct expression is:

```
SELECT is_current FROM sp_table WHERE is_current != 1 OR is_current IS NULL;
```

Finally, it's worth noting that you can't replace that expression with: `SELECT is_current FROM sp_table WHERE is_current != 1` because in SQLite `NULL != 1` evaluates false. You must explicitly check is `is_current IS NULL`.

[SQLite reference](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html)

Comment: In many cases where `NULL` is possible, the [ifnull function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#ifnull) is very helpful.